# What is better way to display reports on homepage?

Tags: usability, interaction-design

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I've reports to displayed on home page. How can we display this view in a better way? No Scroll. I need to display 36 reports without any scroll.

Comment: Why have separate download links that are so far away that one can hardly see where they belong to? I would make the actual report name the download link, and move the date and the name closer together. Then have 2 columns of this (i.e. 18 reports per column). Maybe this is sufficient to fit on one page without scrolling.

Comment: Agree with you @UweKeim , it is also depends upon the user.

Comment: @UweKeim we are formulating new design for this.

Comment: Do you need to display it without scroll for mobile too?

Comment: @Alvaro Me may remove some

Comment: Is there any way to drop the "Startup Landscape Global" wording from every single link? It seems a bit redundant.

Comment: Scroll is most common and powerful mechanism to view content, Secondly it is a part of implicit learning. I think you should try scroll, else  user experience might not be that worthy.

Comment: Another possibility -- although it won't show all reports on one page at once -- is to group the reports into categories (e.g. either by subject or date). Present a grid of buttons/panels on the first page, one per category. Clicking on any of these will list the reports in that category.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution. Just keep header part fix and let data field scrollable or you can put paging. Here I have give filter in separate section but you can directly put filter in month column. See below image :

[image]

**EDITED**
You can display report by default month wise as I gave in example screen and if user want to see all then just divide it multiple columns as @Rob did.

Comment: I forgot to mention. No scroll allowed.

Comment: @NB4 Ok so is there any fix number of reports which are generated every month

Answer (score 0):

You comment scroll is not an option, I guess so are horizontal or vertical slides. Some ways to approach it:

- **Reduce the size of the elements**. Including the download action in the title (as @UweKeim suggests) or just an icon, also the date format and maybe truncating the text if it is necessary.
- Maximise space as much as you can by utilising **several columns like in a grid**.
- Hide some of the content under an **expand button** or hover interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Below options you can try

- you can add the pagination if the number of reports crosses some
  threshold (you can be creative with how you design pagination).
- you can make this report container a fixed height one and allow scroll
  which is not a bad thing to do as users wont mind scrolling for the
  information which is worth to them.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can take out the "Get this report" because you already mention "Download our sample sector reports" though, then you can manage them into a horizontal button like this:
Or make a column like this:
[image]

and make the color of the font "blue" to make sure that is a link.